# Redis does not install on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed redis several times the same way (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it worked fine. This time I did it on my DELL XPS 13 laptop, followed all the steps and when I try to start it using:

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: Started Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: redis.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: redis.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Okt 04 18:23:09 sasa-dell systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error because I forgot to run:

```
sudo make install
```

inside the redis-stable folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to redis.io site

And Open the terminal enter the following commands bold only

**apt-cache policy redis-server**

sudo apt-get install redis-server - Don't getting install this way

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install build-essential tcl**

**mkdir redis** - creating new folder

Download, extract and compile Redis with:

**wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-4.0.11.tar.gz**
**tar xzf redis-4.0.11.tar.gz**
**cd redis-4.0.11**
**make**
The binaries that are now compiled are available in the src directory. Run Redis with:

if once finish you can see the "make test" command

**make test** - run the command

**src/redis-server** - You can interact with Redis using the built-in client:

**src/redis-cli**
redis> **set name vadivel**
OK
redis> **get name**
"vadivel"

**sudo make install** - whenever give the redis command on enter the any dir